# Trying to copy a Java Linked List...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, list, loops, linked-list, copy

So I want to make a separate list as to not manipulate the one being put in through my method parameters. Basically I want "result" to be the same as "p" when the loop ends...but for some reason it's not coming out right.

```
private static Node<Integer> multByScalarAndCarry(Node<Integer> p , int k, int c){
          int carry = c; //carry is taken from parameter
          Node<Integer> result = new Node<Integer>();
          Node<Integer> z = result; //head for the copy list
          Node<Integer> P = p; //pointer for the list being copied
          //copy p into result
          while(P.next!=null){
              z.item = P.item;
              z.next = new Node<Integer>();
              z = z.next;
              P = P.next;
          }
...
}
```

Ignore k and c, they are irrelevant to my question. I am so close to finishing this method and this is the last piece I need. Please help!

Edit [SOLUTION]:
For those who have this issue in the future, I did some thinking using a separate method that copies lists.

Here is a recursive solution:

```
private static Node<Integer> copyNode(Node<Integer> p){
       if(p == null) //if empty, return the same thing
           return p;
       Node<Integer> result = new Node<Integer>();
       result.item = p.item;// construct a node item copy of p's item
       result.next = copyNode(p.next); //attach list doing this for all nodes of p
       return result; //return the result.
}
```

Comment: does [`Node.cloneNode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#cloneNode%28boolean%29) not suffice?

Comment: What does "not coming out right" mean, more specifically?

Comment: "Not coming out right" means that everything is the same except for some reason the last Node does not have a value of null (has item of null and next of null but is not null).

And this Node was made from scratch, we are supposed to do everything like this from scratch. Sorry for the bad english

Comment: The last node is not null because you instantiate it to be a new `Node<Integer>` and then break the loop when p is null, if you simply added `z = null` after your loop was over it would copy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z=z.next is the problem. You are changing the current node to the one you instances in the line before.